# C++ Trying to display data of different types using a template output function

Tags: c++, templates

I have made a function that is supposed to output data types which include ints, chars, strings and a class called item. This is the function:

```
template < typename T >
void Output(const T* first, const T* last, char outforchar= '\0')
{
  if (outforchar== '\0')
  {
    std::for_each(first, last, [](T i){std::cout << i;});
  }
  else 
  {
    std::for_each(first, last, [outforchar](T i){std::cout << i << outforchar;});
  }
}
```

While this function works for types like ints, chars, and strings. It doesn't work for the item class which has a >> operator which formats the input according to the specifications. The compiler throws this error:

```
./tempsorter.h:14:47: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
     std::for_each(beg, end, [](T i){std::cout << i;});
                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:39:0,
                 from psort.cpp:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ostream:602:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Product]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/algorithm:62:0,
                 from ./tempsorter.h:2,
                 from psort.cpp:18:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:4411:5: error: ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = const Item*; _Funct = Output(const T*, const T*, char) [with T = Item]::__lambda0]’, declared using local type ‘Output(const T*, const T*, char) [with T = Item]::__lambda0’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
     for_each(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Function __f)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:4411:5: error: ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = const Item*; _Funct = Output(const T*, const T*, char) [with T = Item]::__lambda1]’, declared using local type ‘Output(const T*, const T*, char) [with T = Item]::__lambda1’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

I understand this error and can get rid of it using something like:

```
for (auto i = first; i != last; ++i) 
{
  std::cout << i;
}
```

But then this gives me incorrect outputs so I can't use it at all.

I am expected to traverse through the various types with something like the following:

```
for (typename E::ConsItr i = e.Begin(); i != e.End(); ++i)
```

I can't seem to understand how to implement this into the function, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that you failed to provide a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
[](T const& i){std::cout << i;}
```

is probably better.  In addition, you probably wrote your `<<` operator wrong.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const SomeType& x)
```

it should look like that, and possibly be a friend of your type.  Ensure it is in the same namespace as your type.  Or you overloades `>>` instead of `<<`

Comment: The output operator was the problem in the class file. For some reason, it was commented out. Whoops! I really appreciate your time.